# Cant get into GET request when sending data in the URL

Tags: javascript, get, postman

Im testing my API with postman, when I try to send data in the URL Postman responds with 404 Not found. I guess Its the format but searching around I think its correct. Can anyone throw some light please?

But when I dont send any data in the URL it works just fine:

When I try to send data in the get request:
[image]

```js
app.get("/mediciones/sigfox_libelium/:{device}", (req, res) => {
    const { device } = req.params;
    res.json("im in");
    console.log("Im in");
    console.log(device);
    console.log(req.params.device);
```

When I send no data on the request works just fine(it crashes but its becouse its not finished yet):
[image]

```js
app.get("/mediciones/sigfox_libelium", (req, res) => {
    const { device} = req.params;
    res.json("im in");
    console.log("Im in");
    console.log(device);
    console.log(req.params.device);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you're using Express.js to build API right?
I think you use `req.params` in the wrong way.

If you want params name `device`
You have to use `:device` instead of `:{device}` in url path.
Like this

```
app.get("/mediciones/sigfox_libelium/:device", (req, res) => {
    cosnt { device } = req.params // You can get device here
})
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I guess I saw the wrong blog, the format on the URL is wrong.